# Pivot sql query with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, where-clause

I have the following script to produce a pivot output, however I am struggling with 2 elements:

1- Having the output showing the output with all userIDs down the left hand side of the output.

2- Putting a where clause in the script which limits the outputs. Tried 100's of options. Any help would be appreciated

```
SELECT 'invoices.USERID' AS totalvalue,
[1], [2]


FROM

(SELECT invoices.USERID, [total],PAYERCODE
FROM invoices
where invoices.userid = 41
  ) AS SourceTable

PIVOT
(
SUM([total])
FOR PAYERCODE IN ([1], [2])
) AS PivotTable;
```

[image]

So what I would like it to look like is

[image]

Any help will be very much appreciated before it messes up my whole weekend.

Comment: Provide sample data.

Comment: When you filter the data to contain only userId `41` why would you expect other userId's in result. Remove the dingle quotes around `invoices.USERID` in final select. It will make the compiler to think as String rather than identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Y-Axis was a string `'invoices.USERID'`

and remove the `WHERE invoices.userid = 41`

```
SELECT USERID AS totalvalue,[1],[2]
FROM 
(SELECT invoices.USERID, [total],PAYERCODE
 FROM invoices
 --where invoices.userid = 41
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
SUM([total])
FOR PAYERCODE IN ([1], [2])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Perfect john. Thanks that works a treat. Sorry I meant to take out the where before posting. I was aware of that. The '' was the issue. Cheers

Comment: @HAS Happy it helped